# Default mount options on auto-mounted NTFS partitions (how to add `noexec` and `fmask=0111`?)

Tags: 10.04, mount, automount, ntfs, default

I use auto-mounting of external USB devices, and it works as expected, except that NTFS partitions are mounted with executability flag on. For example:

```
/dev/sdb1 on /media/Elements type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,blksize=4096,default_permissions)
```

All normal files are `-rwxrwxrwx` on this partition. I am not happy with the `x`s. I know I can have it mounted the way I want if I pass the `fmask=0111` option.

Now I use Lucid, and suppose it uses some new auto-mounting mechanism (`gvfs-mount`?), but I don't really know how the default mounting options can be changed now. Gconf settings in `/system/storage/default_options/ntfs/mount_options` have no effect.

So, how do I make `fmask=0111` the default automounting option for all NTFS partitions? (I'd be grateful also if someone explains how the current automounting mechanism works, how to configure it<strike>, and if the default mounting options are hard-coded, what I have to recompile to change them</strike>).

I know that I can put a line in the `/etc/fstab` and/or mount manually, but this is not the solution I want, because 1) I don't want to edit `/etc/fstab` for each and every external drive I use, 2) fstab records appear in the Places pane of Nautilus, even if the drives are not present. The questions is how to change the *defaults*.

Update: [installing `udisks 1.0.1+git20100614`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16730/#17913) or later gives more sensible defaults for NTFS, the problem which remains is how the user can specify arbitrary mount options.

Comment: These are probably related bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-mount/+bug/78505 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/14335 and many duplicates. The problem seems to be solved in [udisks 1.0.1+git20100614-1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/udisks/1.0.1+git20100614-1), but it is not available for Lucid yet.

Comment: Too bad this question was closed. I'm also looking for a way to force specific mount options for specifc automounted filesystems.

Comment: @mivk I also think the closing wasn't appropriate. I was seeking a way to make NTFS drives mount with "windows_names" automatically...

Answer (score 1):

> if the default mounting options are hard-coded, what I have to recompile to change them

Edit the file *device.c* with your custom defaults:

```
mkdir -p build/udisks
cd build/udisks
apt-get source udisks
gedit udisks-1.0.1/src/device.c
```

Search for `ntfs_defaults`, edit, save and exit.
If the mount option isn't already on `ntfs_allow` list below `ntfs_defaults`, must also add that new option to `ntfs_allow`.

Build (see the other answer for a *pbuilder* way):

```
cd udisks-1.0.1
dch -l custom "Mount custom defaults fix."
dpkg-buildpackage -b -us -uc -rfakeroot
```

Install the newly compiled udisk:

```
sudo dpkg -i ../udisks_1.0.1-1ubuntu1custom1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: 1) I asked about _NTFS_, not FAT. 2) I don't see how the proposed patch (`15-vfat-UTC.patch`) would allow to configure `noexec` and `fmask` mount options for NTFS partitions. As is, your answer is offtopic and not useful.

Comment: @jetxee 1) Look at the line: `gedit udisks-1.0.1/src/device.c` I don't want to help **only** you, but as general help. 2) Just an example about how to share **your** patch against **your** specific problem. **I** won't do **your** homework every time **you** want to change every other default. Just search for _defaults_ when where in _device.c_

Comment: 1) your "general help" on how to build packages is incomplete, inappropriate and badly written, try to be more specific next time; your last edit at least makes the answer on-topic (+1), but you could have stopped after "new option to allow", without loads of copy-paste 2) I did my homeworks long time ago, and in particular, have already posted [a similar workaround](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16730/default-mount-options-on-auto-mounted-ntfs-partitions-how-to-add-noexec-and-f/17913#17913), the problem which remains is: _it still doesn't allow to specify arbitrary mount options_.

Comment: @jetxee 1) You should build after edit _device.c_ stoping there left another question open: How to build? 2) I found your self-answer useful to my specific problem, so I give to the community whats community gives to my: I _specify arbitrary mount options_ following your directions (with customs detours) 3) You edited too much: my compile time is much less than yours and install less garbage than _pbuilder_ 4) I agree to remove the `share your changes` part, that includes the `cp -p` backup line: `apt-get source` will undo just fine any fail.

Comment: Agree. Now it is a well-written answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for the problem of executable files on Lucid (it shouldn't be required on Maverick). Newer [`udisks 1.0.1+git20100614`](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/udisks/1.0.1+git20100614-1) doesn't make all files on NTFS partition executable. This solves my particular problem with executable files, but it still doesn't allow to specify arbitrary mount options.

The following are step-by-step instruction how I built a back-ported `udisks` package.

Change directory to where you want to download the source packages and download them:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/udisks/1.0.1+git20100614-1/+files/udisks_1.0.1+git20100614.orig.tar.gz
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/udisks/1.0.1+git20100614-1/+files/udisks_1.0.1+git20100614-1.debian.tar.gz 
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/maverick/+source/udisks/1.0.1+git20100614-1/+files/udisks_1.0.1+git20100614-1.dsc
```

To build newer `udisks` I used `pbuilder`:

```
sudo aptitude install pbuilder
sudo pbuilder create
sudo pbuilder --update
sudo pbuilder --build udisks_1.0.1+git20100614-1.dsc
```

This may take some time but it worked for me. Now you can install the newly built package:

```
cd /var/cache/pbuilder/result/
ls *.deb
sudo dpkg -i udisks_1.0.1+git20100614-1_amd64.deb
```

This package should be preferred over the distribution (`lucid`) packages:

```
$ apt-cache policy udisks
udisks:
  Installed: 1.0.1+git20100614-1
  Candidate: 1.0.1+git20100614-1
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.1+git20100614-1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.1-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Packages
     1.0.1-1build1 0
        500 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
```

Now the regular files on automatically mounted NTFS partitions are not executable anymore. I hope this fix finds its way into the official Lucid updates.

Comment: In my Ubuntu 16.04 files in NTFS partitions are still executable by default. I had to configure the drive in fstab to fix it.

Answer (score -2):

This is because NTFS drives aren't made for linux, they're made for Windows, and Windows makes everything executable by default.

The only way to have them set to non-executable by default is to edit the fstab for each drive, or switch them to fat32.

Comment: This answers the wrong question. NTFS partitions work well in Linux, and the executable bit can be disabled on all files with fmask=0111 option. The question is how I can I configure the modern _Ubuntu_ _automounting_ mechanism?

Comment: you can't, read the second paragraph. You would have to switch all of those drives to fat32 to keep them compatible and non-executable by default.

Comment: Choosing FAT32 or NTFS has nothing to do with setting the fmask.

Comment: But by default files on fat32 drives are set to not executable. Hence kind of a solution.